# Can anyone explain me what this Python 3 command do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am a **beginner** in Python programming. I have checked what the methods does separately, but not getting as a whole. Here is a program was written as a answer for the problem: 
*Write a program to print all elements of an array in reverse order*:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':                          #1   
    n = int(input())                                #2
                                                    #3
    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))  #4
    for i in range(n):                              #5
        print(arr[-i-1],end=' ')                    #6
```

I am not getting line 4. Can anyone explain step by step what that line is doing? How they are working and giving the output as a whole? The inputs were separated by space:

```
5            #length of the array
1 2 3 4 5     #inputs separated by space
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`input()` looks like it gets the next line of input.
From the example this is the string `"1 2 3 4 5\n"` (it has a newline on the end).

`rstrip()` then removes whitespace at the right end of the input, including the newline.

`split()` with no arguments splits on whitespace, transforming the input to an iterable of strings. e.g. `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

`map(int, sequence)` applies int to each string. e.g. `int('1') -> 1`, `int('2') -> 2` etc.. So your sequence of strings is now a sequence of integers.

Finally `list(seq)` transforms the sequence to a list type. So now you have `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: From where rstrip() removes whitespace

Comment: rstrip() "strips" the right end of the string, removing whitespace. This includes spaces, tabs and newlines. So your input() is `"12345\n"` and then rstrip() gives `"12345"` only.

Comment: Map calls a function (arg1) on each item in the sequence (arg2). In your example, function is `int` function. And the sequence is the strings "1", "2", "3", "4", "5". The result is to convert strings of numbers to integer sequence. It looks the same when you print, but string "1"+"2" is "12". But integer 1+2 = 3.

Comment: So in python the input always changes into string automatically?  No matter what I gave as input (integer or float) ? as, the input when giving is `1 2 3 4 5` but, you are saying that input() is `"12345\n"`. Do I need to use this line 4 in every program incluidng array then?

Comment: @tarit You're looking at it the wrong way. Your input is not covered to a string - it is a string (even if it is a string of digits)! What happens is that the string is simply not converted to anything.

Answer (score 3):

It is a "pythonic" way of creating a `list` of `int`s from a space seperated numeric input:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

It takes a string input and transforms it into a list of integers using result of [map(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which returns a generator.

[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) takes a function and applies it to all elements of the second argument iterable.

[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).
[rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).
[split()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
takes an input, removes all whitespaces on the right side and splits it into parts on whitespaces which is then fed as iterable into `map(int, ...)` which creates a generator result from applying `int` to all elements of the given iterable. The result of map is fed into `list(...)` which makes a list from it.

```
"1 2 3 4" => ["1","2","3","4"] -> generator (1,2,3,4) -> [1,2,3,4]
```

This will break with an error if you supply non-numbers or anything other then spaces and numbers - no error handling is done.

It is short, but only safe if the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

`input()`: By default it takes string as an input.

The `map(aFunction, aSequence)` function applies a passed-in function to each item in an iterable object and returns a list containing all the function call results. So, all the string entries which are separated by a space are converted into integer.

Reference: `https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php`

`split()`: This function is used to split all the entries in the string by space.

`rstrip()`: This function is used to strip out the spaces if any present at the end of the array input `(1 2 3 4 5)`

Comment: map returns a generator - not a list.

Comment: rstrip only stripps from the right of the string - not from any array and not from the left side.

Comment: it is nice to contribute to SO but ... as a sidenote: your answer adds nothing new compared to the already existing answers...